# Doxygen \xrefitem heading

Tags: doxygen

I use doxygen and wonder if my understanding for
\xrefitem and "heading" is correct?

In my code I have:

```
//! \xrefitem Cars "heading" "ListName" 
//! Text
```

Here I define a key "Cars". All occurences of this key will be put to the "Related Pages" menu. There will be a link with "ListName" under which all occurences of the related artefacts with that key will appear.

Now my hope was that "heading" is changeable and items of the same key will be put under "ListName" but under different "headings".

```
//! \xrefitem Cars "Audi" "ListName" 
//! Text

//! \xrefitem Cars "Mercedes" "ListName" 
//! Text
```

But whatever I enter for "headings" it is not shown, likewise "Audi" or "Mercedes".

Can anybody explain the purpose of "heading" and what I can do with it and if my understanding is correct?

I read the manual now dozens of times but just do not get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a good idea to follow the advice in the manual and use an ALIAS.  This helps to make it clear that changing the parameters (e.g. "Audi" to "Mercedes") is meaningless.

To takes the manual's example

```
ALIASES += "reminder=\xrefitem reminders \"Reminder\" \"Reminders\""
```

and using

```
/reminder Make Coffee
```

will result in something like

```
Reminder 
  Make Coffee
```

i.e. Heading, Text

on a page labelled

```
Reminders
```

i.e. ListName

Hope that helps - I'm a bit rusty and working from memory here.

Comment: I reanalysed and can confirm that the heading "Reminder" is used to be displayed e.g. in the html description of a function, but if I change it then to "Reminder2" still "Reminder" will be displayed. For this it is meaningless.